# How to start React Native App in portrait orientation only in both iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to start React Native app with Portrait orientation. Currently I'm using the [react-native-orientation-locker](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker) library to handle the initial orientation. But it's not working correctly.

My App.js looks like this.

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';

export const App = () => {
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        Orientation.lockToPortrait();
    }, []);

    return (
        <RootContainer>
            <MyApp />
        </RootContainer>
    );
};

export default App;
```

I think this has to be handled from the native side because the JavaScript codes run after the initial process. Maybe I have to add a code MainApplication.java and AppDelegate.mm?

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until you lock the orientation. See the example below:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';

const App = () => {
  const [appReady, setAppReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    Orientation.lockToPortrait();
    setAppReady(true);
  }, []);

  if (!appReady) {
    return <Text>Loading</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <RootContainer>
      <MyApp />
    </RootContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the application to have a static orientation and not allow it to change dynamically inside of the app, you should add the orientation natively for both Android and iOS.

**For Android:**

Open up `AndroidManifest.xml` and add the following inside of the application tag

`android:screenOrientation="portrait`
So you'd have something like this

```xml
    <activity 
      android:name=".MainActivity" 
      android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" 
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

**For iOS:**

Open up xCode and inside of the general tab, go down to Deployment info and check the Portrait box

[image]